# method responsible for name in top view

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

[image]

I want to change the name that is colored in my picture. what method is responsible for its display? I tried with `name_get` but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should define a computed field and in the related function make your custom name with any logic that you want and for _rec_name use this computed field for example:

```
class Test(models.Model):
_name = "test"
_description = 'test for custom rec name'
_rec_name = 'record_name'

t1 = fields.Char()
t2 = fields.Char()
record_name = fields.Char(compute="_set_record_name", store=False)
def _set_record_name(self):
    for record in self:
        record.record_name = record.t1 + record.t2
```

you can set anything you want to compute field

Answer (score 0):

It is responsible for `rec_name` attribute at model level. You can modify with combination of fields or one field as you want. You need to write it in .py file.

JFI, `name_get()` method use to display in dropdown (many2one) field.

Comment: i know that i can add field in rec_name, but i need to change this to my custom name, not name from field

Comment: Yes. You can. You can introduce new field and set that field in `rec_name`

Comment: It's some kinda workaround... i think there should be a method resposible for that